# Android: Show Listview when clicking on EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listener

I don't know if this is the right method but I would like to know if is it possible to show a Listview when the user clicks on an EditText/TextView and show afterwards the selected item text in this EditText. I know how to declare  the EditText in the layout but is there any example of when clicking on the listener show the ListView? Do I need to add this Listview in the XML layout or do I have to add it programatically?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about suggestion text?

Comment: I'm looking forward to know id this is the right method or if there are better methods for doing this.

Comment: you can use alert list which gives the user a popup list for selection and after user selection you can update Textview or edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, a I was looking just for a Spinner, I thought that it was another type of ListView

Answer (score 0):

if your app wants to have a sort of text viewand when you click on it you need to show up a list view then you can use **expandable list view** check this tutorial

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/